# How to visualize hashtags in R, and see the trends of the hashtags?

Tags: r, hashtag

I'm doing trend analysis, and trying to use barcharts to visualize the frequencies of the hashtags in different years. So I can see the top 3 most frequent hashtag terms, and see how the frequencies of these terms are evolving during years I have a dataset like this:

```
    terms          year
1   #A;#B;#C       2017
2   #B;#C;#D       2016
3   #C;#D;#E       2021
4   #D;#E;#F       2020
5   #E;#F;#G       2020
6   #F;#G;#H       2020
7   #G;#H;#I       2019
8   #H;#I;#J       2018
9   #I;#J;#K       2020
10  #J;#K;#L       2020
```

thanks!

Comment: So a barchart for each year ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, we need to count the hashtag for every year. Since the hashtags for a particular year is in single-column we need to separate it into different columns and then we can convert the df into a long df, where it becomes possible for us to group it based on year and hashtag to find the count.

```r
library(tidyverse)

structure(list(terms = c("#A;#B;#C", "#B;#C;#D", "#C;#D;#E", 
                         "#D;#E;#F", "#E;#F;#G", "#F;#G;#H", "#G;#H;#I", "#H;#I;#J", "#I;#J;#K", 
                         "#J;#K;#L"), year = c(2017, 2016, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2019, 
                                               2018, 2020, 2020)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                      "tbl", "data.frame")) -> df

df %>% 
   separate(terms, into = paste0("t", 1:3), sep = ";") %>% 
   pivot_longer(-year) %>% 
   group_by(year, value) %>% 
   count(value) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n, fill = value, label = n)) +
   geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
   geom_text(position = position_dodge(1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your answer. However, if I have too many hashtags, how to automate it, rather than type is one by one? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you mean by typing one by one. The data will have all the hashtags and the code is completely automated. Depending upon the number of hashtags and year you may need to change how you display your plot like maybe a facet plot by year or a group of hastag.

Comment: I don't really understand into = paste0("t", 1:3), could you please explain? thank you!

Comment: Here 3 hashtags so we need to create 3 new columns and provide column names for that. If you don't know the number of hashtags you can give some large number here and the columns without hastags will return `NA`

Comment: Yes I have lots of NA's, how to remove them from the barchat? 
And in this case, why in 2020 you have 5 values, while other years has 3?

Comment: and I want to add label to the bars, but only to those with higher frequencies. I used: label = value, which gives a label to every bar, and then it's not visible anymore because there are too many text in the chart... Is there a way which I can only show the label for the bars with higher frequencies, and give the labels nice position? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new Data frame were every hashtag gets a unique information for year.

After that you can play around with the data using geom_bar.

I can not upload the plot to this post as this is a new account.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

#your Data:

#terms          year
#1   #A;#B;#C       2017
#2   #B;#C;#D       2016
#3   #C;#D;#E       2021
#4   #D;#E;#F       2020
#5   #E;#F;#G       2020
#6   #F;#G;#H       2020
#7   #G;#H;#I       2019
#8   #H;#I;#J       2018
#9   #I;#J;#K       2020
#10  #J;#K;#L       2020

# make a df that looks like your data:
terms<- c("#A;#B;#C",
          "#B;#C;#D",
          "#C;#D;#E",
          "#D;#E;#F",
          "#E;#F;#G",
          "#G;#H;#I",
          "#H;#I;#J",
          "#I;#J;#K",
          "#J;#K;#L")

terms<-as.data.frame(terms)
year<-c(2017,2016,2021,2020,2020,2019,2018,2020,2020)        
year<-as.data.frame(year)
df<-cbind(terms,year)

# read your data from what I assume is your Data frame
terms<-c(df$terms)
year.list<-c(df$year)

loopcount<-length(terms)

# make new dummys
year<-c()
hashtags<-c()

all.years<-as.data.frame(hashtags,year)
#split hashtags based on ";"
hashtag.list<-str_split(terms, ";")
```

With this loop you create a new DF

```
# make new df were every hashtags gets the information for year
for (i in 1:loopcount){
   hashtags<-hashtag.list[[i]]
   hashtags<-as.data.frame(hashtags)
   
   year<-c()
   for(k in 1:nrow(hashtags)) {
     year[k]<- year.list[i]
   }
   year<-as.data.frame(year)
   one.year<-cbind(hashtags,year)
   
   all.years<-rbind(all.years,one.year)
 }

hashtagDF<-all.years


head(hashtagDF)
```

The new DF can then be used to to plot what you want

Or
if I understand you correct

you can make a new df were the frequency of the hashtags per year are shown
and only the top 3 hashtags are included

```
#only include the three most used hashtags per year

# dummys for new df
hashtags<-c()
year<-c()
Freq<-c()

top.3<-as.data.frame(hashtags,year,Freq)

years.in.study<-unique(hashtagDF$year)
#i<-3
for ( i in 1: length(years.in.study)){
  what.year<-paste(years.in.study[i])
  #subset per year
one.subset<-subset(hashtagDF, year == what.year)


# calculate how often a hashtag is present per year
freq<-table(one.subset)
frequency.per.year<-as.data.frame(freq)
frequency.per.year<-frequency.per.year[order(-frequency.per.year[,3]), ]

# only keep the 3 most occurring terms
  lenght.of.file.to.delete<-nrow(frequency.per.year)
if (nrow(frequency.per.year) == 3){
  lenght.of.file.to.delete<-lenght.of.file.to.delete+1
  }
frequency.per.year<-frequency.per.year[-c(4:lenght.of.file.to.delete), ]

# make a df with all years
top.3<-rbind(top.3,frequency.per.year)

}

top.3


#order for year
top.3$year<-as.character(top.3$year)
top.3[order(top.3[,2]), ]

#year should be a factor
top.3$yearF<-as.factor(top.3$year)
```

Then you can plot it

```
# plot as barplot
# with
# the frequencies of the hashtags in different years.
# the top 3 most frequent hashtag terms per year


barplot<-ggplot(data=top.3, aes(x=yearF, y=Freq,fill=hashtags)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  labs(title = "",
       subtitle = "",
       caption = "",
       x= "", 
       y= "")


barplot


ggsave(file="hashtag.png", barplot, width = 210, height = 297, units = "mm")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: thanks for the comment.

I can not post pictures yet
But I can annotate the code more...

Comment: Hi thanks! what if I have too many hashtags, not only #A #B but like thousands, it's very inconvenient to specify all of them in the dataframe. Is there a way to automate it?

Comment: Hello kvjing,
yes, it will certainly be possible to automate it.

I do not know how you data is structured...

In the code above I read the terms as a vector. It does not matter how large the file is.
I assume you have some sort of data.frame or matrix?
the only problem would be that this code is most definitely not optimised for speed but for readability.

Best regards

Comment: hi yes my hashtags are like vectors, could you please help to clean up a bit with your code? I get a bit lost... thank you very much!

Comment: What you need to do first:

create a df were every term (one hashtag) gets the information for year.
this is done by the first loop.
you can use lapply as well here and it would be faster if that is an issue.

after that you want the frequency - or the number a hashtag occurs in a year.
and you only want the 3 most common hasthags per year.
this is done with the second loop.


After I rebuild your shown data frame I build a new one to compute what I described above.

So, you do not need to type in your data manualy but just use the terms and information for year as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a nicely readable plot for each year in `Base R`, we can do the following:

**Code**

```
# First create a list of data.frames that we can utilize to plot

# Split by year
listdf <- split(df, df$year)

# Only choose trends and name list according to year
listdf <- lapply(listdf, "[[", 1)

# Stringsplit to obtain trends as vector for each year
listdfplot <- lapply(listdf, function(x){
  unlist(strsplit(x, ";"))
})


# Plot 
# Plot side by side
par(mfrow = c(2, 3))

# A barplot for each year 
Map(function(x, y){
  barplot(table(x), main = paste("Trends in", y), las = 2)
},
listdfplot,
names(listdfplot))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(terms = c("#A;#B;#C", "#B;#C;#D", "#C;#D;#E", 
                         "#D;#E;#F", "#E;#F;#G", "#F;#G;#H", "#G;#H;#I", "#H;#I;#J", "#I;#J;#K", 
                         "#J;#K;#L"), year = c(2017, 2016, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2019, 
                                               2018, 2020, 2020)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                      "tbl", "data.frame"))
```